# How to send USDC-SPL using @solana-labs/web3.js

Tags: solana

I'm able to send SOL tokens using web3.js but have been unable to do so with USDC-SPL tokens. This is my current code for sending SOL tokens:

```js
 // .......
 const connection = new Connection(network);
 const transaction = new Transaction()
  .add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: publicKey,
      toPubkey: to,
      lamports: Number(amount) * 1000000000,
    })
  );
  const { blockhash } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
  transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
  transaction.feePayer = publicKey;
  let signedTransaction: any = null;
  if ("solana" in window) {
    signedTransaction = await window.solana.signTransaction(transaction)
  } else if ("solflare" in window) {
    signedTransaction = await window.solflare.signTransaction(transaction);
  }
 // .......
```

The answers I've seen earlier are from people sending their own custom made tokens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All SPL tokens (including USDC token) on Solana are owned by spl-token program.

So you can send USDC in the same way as sending your own custom made tokens by changing the token address to
`EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v` (this is the USDC SPL token address on solana mainnet).

For example:

```js
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as splToken from "@solana/spl-token";

const DEMO_WALLET_SECRET_KEY = new Uint8Array([
    ...
  ]);

const SOLANA_MAINNET_USDC_PUBKEY = "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v";

(async () => {
  // Connect to cluster
  var connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
  // Construct wallet keypairs
  var fromWallet = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(DEMO_WALLET_SECRET_KEY);
  var toWallet = web3.Keypair.generate();
  
  // Construct my token class
  var USDC_pubkey = new web3.PublicKey(SOLANA_MAINNET_USDC_PUBKEY);
  var USDC_Token = new splToken.Token(
    connection,
    USDC_pubkey,
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    fromWallet
  );
  // Create associated token accounts for my token if they don't exist yet
  var fromTokenAccount = await USDC_Token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
    fromWallet.publicKey
  )
  var toTokenAccount = await USDC_Token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
    toWallet.publicKey
  )
  // Add token transfer instructions to transaction
  var transaction = new web3.Transaction()
    .add(
      splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        [],
        0
      )
    );
  // Sign transaction, broadcast, and confirm
  var signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [fromWallet]
  );
  console.log("SIGNATURE", signature);
  console.log("SUCCESS");
})();
```

Comment: This uses the user's secret key to perform the transaction, how could I achieve the same thing with Phantom?

Comment: By using wallets like Phantom, you can sign the transaction which has the currently connected account as the signer.

Comment: So there's an issue with this, this doesn't mint the USDC account for a receiver if that person hasn't ever received USDC tokens

Comment: Since different types of tokens are stored on different associated accounts(which are derived from your main wallet), you should create a USDC token's associated token account of the receiver first, if the user didn't ever have USDC tokens. Please read about associated token account program on solana [here](https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account).

Comment: Does Token no longer exist? I get `Property 'Token' does not exist on type 'typeof import("somedir/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/types/index")'.`